# How to use AWS S3 in Aurelia browser application in Javascript/ES6?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I'm trying to use a (public access) AWS.S3 bucket in an aurelia application (all aurelia updates done recently). First, I installed the aws-sdk via npm, getting this line into my config.js:

```
"npm:aws-sdk@2.3.11": { ....
```

After importing

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

( I also tried

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

before duncanhall's answer )

and calling

```
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = "";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "";
AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
```

I just try this:

```
let bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: bucketPath}});
```

getting a

```
"TypeError: AWS.S3 is not a constructor at Function .... "
```

I guess I'm missing something essential?

Big thanks for any hints.

**EDIT:**

Another attempt was to uninstall aws-sdk from npm, download it separately, put it into /scripts/ folder and load it via

```
<script src="scripts/aws-sdk.js"></script>
```

in my main index.html file. Still I become:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/dist/aws-sdk.js 404 (Not Found)
ERROR [app-router] Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/dist/aws-sdk.js
```

Comment: Just a heads up to make sure your IAM user's permissions are locked down! The world will have access to the keys you supply this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it. The simplest solution is to REMOVE all imports of aws-sdk in js-code and to use

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

in the main index.html ... . It just works.

Answer (score 1):

The `aws-sdk` module exposes a single default object.

Try replacing your wildcard import statement with a single definition:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not help.